# iOS - Remove unused class and storyboard for release build

Tags: swift, preprocessor

I have created some utility classes and storyboard files for debugging and development testing purpose in my swift project.
All this will be of no use for app store build and are unnecessarily adding up size of my final .ipa.

I can conditionally compile the code by using pre proccesor flags for **DEBUG** and **RELEASE** mode.
Is there any best approach to do this?
And what is the best approach to remove unused storyboard files for final build?
Do I need to write any script?
Thanks

Comment: I am talking about resources and swift files both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Xcode you can create a build target exclusive to your App store build and make sure that the files you don't want to be part of the release are not included in it.

In the "Build Phases" section of the target configuration, you can control which files will be compiled in (Compile Sources) and/or embedded (Copy Bundle Resources phase).

Comment: I think this would be the best without adding pre procesor flag to remove code and script to remove resources .